# Can I select an element by ref using vue test utils

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

If I have an image

`<img class="pineapple" ref="pineapple" src="pineapple.jpg" />`

Can I use the $ref

`expect(wrapper.find($refs.pineapple).exists()).toBe(true)`

instead of

`expect(wrapper.find('.pineapple').exists()).toBe(true)`

Answer (score 11):

You can pass an object to the `wrapper.find` with the `ref` property.

```js
expect(wrapper.find({ref: 'pineapple'}).exists()).toBe(true)
```

---

From the Vue Test util docs:

### Find Option Object

#### Ref

Using a find option object, Vue Test Utils allows for selecting elements by $ref on wrapper components.

```js
const buttonWrapper = wrapper.find({ ref: 'myButton' })
buttonWrapper.trigger('click')
```

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/selectors.html