# Vue test utils - how to find an element by ref?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I've tried this way: [Can I select an element by ref using vue test utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455763/can-i-select-an-element-by-ref-using-vue-test-utils) which works and is also what the documentation suggests: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/selectors.html. However it gives a warning:

```
console.error node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:1704
    [vue-test-utils]: finding components with `find` or `get` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Use `findComponent` and `getComponent` instead.
```

Is there a proper way of doing this? I'm not trying to find a component, but an element, so `findComponent` doesn't work. I've double checked that I'm testing the correct component and that the element with the correct ref within it exists.